# How do I get VSC python intellisense to work properly?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

### Problem

Since VSC 1.82 my python intellisense has stopped working in concerns to variables, syntax errors and module imports. As example of what my problem is I can mention that earlier the lines

```
i = 1
print(i + 1)
```

would give me a bold light blue "i" in both variable definition and variable call statements. If there was no call for the variable the "i" in the variable definition would appear with a little darker color. No it's only *nobold* white. Other parts of intellisense works. As an example the word "print" appears in light yellow and the parentheses is in an orange color.

As for error checking the line

```
print dnfwerin
```

would give me a waveformed red line under "dnfwerin" to show that something is unrecognised. Now it doesn't show any alerts at all? The line

```
s = 3dfa
```

gives me red characters. That seems to be the best I can provoke VSC to show as an error alert.

### What have I tried

I've tried to uninstall VSC and:

- Downgrade to earlier releases with no success due to library/VSC module compatibility issues.
- Update VSC to whatever latest version I could get my hands on.
- I found some treads that suggested to check some json files. Unfortunately I can't remember exactly what it was or where I found them, but my json-files did look as they where supposed to look when both me and my works IT-support had a look at them.

### About my system/environment

On my local computer I'm now running VSC 1.83.0 (which should be the latest stable version). I faced this problem when we got the update to 1.82.3, I think, it might have been an earlier version of 1.82.

In a server environment we have that is off line due to security and updates of VSC therefore is not triggered in other ways than manually, we're still running VSC 1.59.0 and there everything works as expected.

The python interpretator I'm running (locally) is 3.11.1 (64) on a Windows 10 machine.

### My questions

- Is there any others who faces the same issues with 1.83.0?
- If 1.83.0 works perfectly fine with python for everyone else, what is it that I and my support is missing?

Comment: Do you have `pylance` installed?

Comment: Yes, pylance is installed. Current installed version is 2023.10.10. Forgot to mention that I've even tried to reinstall that package also.

Comment: type `cntrl +` to go to settings then do this **"python.languageServer": "Default"**

Comment: This all works fine on my machine, please report your buggy version. `Ctrl+Shift+P-->Help:About`. As well as showing your error interface.